# How to enable scroll on div when using malihu custom scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, mcustomscrollbar

I am using Malihu custom scrollbar, it works properly on the full page but when I hover the mouse over a div which has list of images, it continues to scroll the page instead of div. I want to scroll div when the cursor is over this div. When I removed mCustomScrollbar, it works fine.

```
this.$('.content').mCustomScrollbar({
   theme: 'minimal',
   mouseWheel: {                        
      disableOver: ['div.className']
   }
});
```

PS: Using this.$('.content').mCustomScrollbar("destroy") is not an option.